# Why I am getting two widths and two heights of sprite in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

Hi I am little confused here I wanted to get width of my "Player" GameObject and I was able to get the width but when I Debug.Log(width) I got two values 12.8 and then 1.33 why is that? I then tried this with height, I got the same problem there were two values for height 9.6 and 1.62 I really don't know what is this.

---

Okay here is my code(I can't comment it, it was too long to be a comment)

```css
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour 
{
 public GameObject obstacle;
 public int score = 0;
 public float width;

 void Start () 
 {
  var renderer = GameObject.Find ("Crate").gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
  width = renderer.bounds.size.x;
  Debug.Log (width);
 }

 void Update () 
 {
  if (obstacle != null && obstacle.transform != null) 
  {
   if(GameObject.Find("Player").transform.position.x >= obstacle.transform.position.x
                                    && 
      GameObject.Find("Player").transform.position.x < obstacle.transform.position.x + (width - 0.9) )
   {
    score++;
    //Debug.Log(score);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's your code rewritten.

Please post a screenshot of your console log including the first two entries of height and width.

```
public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
SpriteRenderer renderer;
Transform player;

public GameObject obstacle;
public int score = 0;
public float width;
public float height;

void Start()
{
    player = (Transform)GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<Transform>();
    renderer = GameObject.Find("Crate").gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

    width = renderer.bounds.size.x;
    height = renderer.bounds.size.y;

    Debug.Log(width);
    Debug.Log(height);
}

void Update()
{
    if (obstacle != null && obstacle.transform != null)
    {
        if (player.position.x >= obstacle.transform.position.x &&
           player.position.x < obstacle.transform.position.x + (width - 0.9))
        {
            score++;
            //Debug.Log(score);
        }
    }
}
}
```